# MYSQL: select by two foreign keys from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

**flights:** id, idcompany, idplane, fromCity, toCity, takeoff...

**companies:** id, name

**planes:** id, name

**cities:** id, name

I want to declare the names of the two cities "fromCity, toCity" in the same query.

MY purpose of this action is get the cities names at once, so I can display them to the client, without any need to do another query to get the cities names.

here is my try:

```
SELECT f.id, f.takeoff, f.arrival, ct.name as fromCity, f.toCity, c.name as company, p.name as plane 
FROM flights f, companies c, planes p, cities ct 
WHERE f.idCompany = c.id AND f.idPlane = p.id AND f.fromCity = ct.id 
ORDER BY f.takeoff ASC
```

this query will return the name of the "fromCity" but the id of the "toCity", so what I can do to get the two names by the same query?

Comment: Add some sample table data, the current result, and the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT 
    f.id, f.takeoff, f.arrival, ct1.name as fromCity
    ,ct2.name as toCity, c.name as company, p.name as plane 
FROM 
    flights f
inner join
    companies c
on
    f.idCompany = c.id 
inner join
    planes p
on
    f.idPlane = p.id
inner join
    cities ct1 
on
    f.fromCity = ct1.id 
inner join
    cities ct2
on
    f.toCity = ct2.id   
ORDER BY 
    f.takeoff ASC;
```

And try **not using** [old-style-join](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) from now on.

Comment: the three answers are rights, now which one has the highest performance?

Answer (score 1):

You have to join the table twice.

```
SELECT f.id, f.takeoff, f.arrival, ct.name as fromCity, f.toCity, c.name as company, p.name as plane , cf.name
FROM flights f, companies c, planes p, cities ct,cities cf 
WHERE f.idCompany = c.id AND f.idPlane = p.id AND f.fromCity = ct.id AND f.toCity = cf.id
ORDER BY f.takeoff ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution is to make two copies of the table cities:

```
SELECT f.id, f.takeoff, f.arrival, ct1.name as fromCity, ct2.name as toCity, c.name as company, p.name as plane 

FROM flights f, companies c, planes p, cities ct1, cities ct2 

WHERE f.idCompany = c.id AND f.idPlane = p.id AND f.fromCity = ct1.id AND ct2.id = f.toCity 

ORDER BY f.takeoff ASC
```

Comment: Pretty much the same as Pham X. Bach's answer, but still with old style, implicit joins...

Comment: @jarlh yeah right, so I'll accept Pham X. Bach's answer